# ezgmail needs manual authentication once a week

Tags: email, gmail

I have been using ezgmail on a raspberry pi 4 for a month now to automatically check and download e-mail attachments every 10 minutes and it's working flawlessly except for an annoying authentication issue.
I think I set up the OAuth correctly (according to the [latest instructions](https://github.com/asweigart/ezgmail)), but after a week of operation with no issues the script asks me to manually do a new authentication:

`Failed to start a local webserver listening on either port 8080`
`or port 8090. Please check your firewall settings and locally`
`running programs that may be blocking or using those ports.`

`Falling back to --noauth_local_webserver and continuing with`
`authorization.`

`Go to the following link in your browser:`

After I'm doing so, the script starts to work for another week again.
Is it a limitation of ezgmail or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

if you're application is still in testing the refresh token will expire after seven days

Go to google cloud console under oauth2 consent screen and set it to production, then authorize it again your refresh token will not expire

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I set the app from "Testing" to "In production" at the Cloud console by Publishing it, but then I'm not able to update the token because I get the following error at the authorization link: "Error 400: invalid_request The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure"
Switching the app back to the "Testing" state allows me to update the token, but it will probably expire in 7 days again as you wrote.

Comment: Can it be the problem that I can't complete the full verification process (YouTube video, Terms of use link, etc.) required for the "In production" state?

Comment: You need to use HTTPS in your code you cant use OOB it was discontinued a long time ago https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration.

Comment: But, why it is working if the app is in "Testing" state?

Comment: production requires https